# iOS ui horizontal time scroll

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

How make to build ui horizontal time scroll, how [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timeli/id386890857?mt=8) app? I was looking for a standard API, which makes the implementation of similar, but found nothing

Comment: I think you simply want a `UIScrollView` that is wider than it is tall, with buttons/images/whatever to indicate your bars.

Comment: when horizontal scroll if element is shifted in left partially, then title stays in left position (near screen). In vertical space element can be in any position. I want to Title has the same behavior. Group of cell in UITable View has same behavior. Title is not moving, until all elements of groups is not ended.